# Changing player direction with keys using C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive been trying to make this Object move forward on its own and turn left or right  in circular fashion if the left/right keys are pressed with unity using C#, this picture will make it clearer: http://prnt.sc/avmxbn

I was only able to make it move on its own and this is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

Update(){ transform.localPosition += transform.forward *speed *Time.deltaTime

float speed = 5.0f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Debug.Log ("it's working?");    

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;


}

void FixedUpdate(){

}
```

}

I have no idea, however, how to change left or right directions in circular paths like the picture linked demonstrates. Anyone able to help me? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want your motions to be physical like motions or straight UpDownLeftRight lines with curved turns?

Comment: @YotamSalmon I hope this will make it clearer, I would like it to go in a continuos direction when keys are not pressed, but when the left and right keys are pressed, the players path should begin curving in the direction of the key that is pressed

Comment: Did you forget to add your code?

Comment: You have asked this question twice. I have answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36804618/3124704).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user entered same question twice.

Comment: In future, please edit your post to add additional details to it, rather than posting the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are obvious errors in your code. You call `Update()` twice. The first time without a return type.  You shouldn't do that. Start by deleting the first `Update()` and the code on the same line.

Then to answer your question you will have to look into getting input from the user. Use `Input.GetKey()` and pass it a `KeyCode` value such as `KeyCode.A`for the 'A' key. So you can say:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    //do something(for example, Turn the player right.)
}
```

Then look into rotating the object using `transform.Roate` to rotate the player.

Comment: I would recommend that to find the angle to rotate you'd need to calculate the distanced travelled during the frame using Time.deltatime*speed,

then using the equation of the length of an arc, backwards-calculate the angle that they will have turned, and then calculate the final position at the end of the arc. That way the player will not only be in the right position but will be facing the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Attach this script to your moving object:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveController : MonoBehaviour {
    float angle = 1F;
    float speed = 0.2F;
    void Update ()
    {
        if ( Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) )
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -angle);
        else if( Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) )
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angle);

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed);
    }
}
```

The key point here is to separate your moving from your rotating functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script for movement :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour {

     public Rigidbody rigidbody;

     float angle = 0f;
     const float SPEED = 1f;
     float multiplier = 1f;

     void FixedUpdate(){

         if ( Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) )
             angle -= Time.deltaTime * SPEED * multiplier;
         else if( Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) )
             angle += Time.deltaTime * SPEED * multiplier;

         rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(angle) * SPEED, Mathf.Cos(angle) * SPEED);

    }
}
```

Multiplier value is inversely proportional to the radius.